# Typescript references misunderstanding

Tags: reference, typescript

I have a TypeScript d.ts file which I'm referencing from another file, but for some reason the exported class definitions don't seem to be recognised.

**foo.d.ts**

```
export declare class MyClass {
    constructor();
    public MyFunc(id: number): void;
}
```

**bar.ts**

```
/// <reference path="typings/MyClass.d.ts" />
class BarClass {
    private something: MyClass;
    constructor(thing: MyClass) {
        this.something = thing;
    }
}
```

That's about as simple an example I can give, but when doing this I get `Could not find symbol 'MyClass'`

I'm sure this used to work prior to updating TypeScript to the latest version, but on checking the breaking changes, I can't see anything which would cause the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the export keyword. i.e

```
export declare class MyClass {
    constructor();
    public MyFunc(id: number): void;
}
```

to

```
declare class MyClass {
    constructor();
    public MyFunc(id: number): void;
}
```

Reason: The `export` keyword at the root of the file is reserved for external modules. A video on external modules : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Fantastic thank you, it was from a d.ts from definitely typed, I will send a pull request when I get a sec

Comment: @dougajmcdonald You can also shorthand your class to: `class BarClass { constructor(private something: MyClass) { } }`